# sorting list of items with specific field on sales order item sublist NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I like to sort the list of items in the dropdown in the standard NetSuite sublist `item`. Let's say items are sorted with the name when clicked on >> to open the dropdown list.

Is this possible to sort this list with any other fields, maybe a custom field on items record. let's say I add a custom field on the item record (every item), which is some numbers.

displaying that list with the order by that field.

I have seen a way around to create a custom sublist of my own requirement and then hide the standard and show the custom on a specific record by customizing the form.

Comment: any word on this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue once, I did the following:

1. You can create a new body field or sublist field based on your business using **userevent script(before load)**.
2. Create a search with the required order(you can do any operation to prepare your data) after that you filled the result manually to the new custom field.
3. Whenever the user selects a value in the custom field you set the original one to be the same as the custom one. For this one, you will need a client script.

Note: you can show your custom field and hide or disable the original field only not the whole list since the client script will be responsible to set the value to it. using this approach will not require you to add or edit any of your records which will be helpful if you have a complex process and a lot of dependencies. This approach worked for my issue I hope to be helpful to you too.